# Multiple If Statements in a Row with jQuery

Tags: jquery, api, if-statement, youtube

I would like to add multiple if statements to a function. I am using YouTube's iFrame API to do different actions when the video is play or paused. I currently have the following code:

```
      function onPlayerStateChange(newState) {
        console.log(newState);

        if (newState.data == 1) {
          //do something
          return false;
        } else {
          //do something else
          return false;
        }
      }
```

It works great when I only have the first if statement, but breaks when I add the else clause to it. How do you check for multiple conditions like this with jQuery?

Comment: What does this have to do with jQuery? Did you mean `javascript`?

Answer (score 1):

Use a `switch` on `newState.data`, like this:

```
switch(newState.data){
    case 1:
       //do something
       //break or return true/false
    case 2:
       //Do something else
       break;
    case 3:
       break;
    default:
       //Do something when newState.data is NOT 1, 2 or 3
       break;
}
```

Comment: This is a great answer. However, these are basic Javascript constructs, and not jQuery specific. I would advise the OP to read up on javascript :-)

Comment: Hmm, that doesn't seem to work. Do you have to go through every possible case? If you don't want it to do something for a case can you only insert "break;"?

Comment: If you don't want it do anything on specific cases, you can do 2 things: 1) Leave it out - this will make it go to the `default` case. 2) Do what you suggest yourself, this will do nothing and break out of the `switch`-case, and continue with the code following the `switch`

Answer (score 0):

Your code with the `if ... else` is an "either-or" approach. It's not entirely clear to me what you're trying to do. However, the *syntax* is valid so it must be the logic that fails.

If you want to do multiple independent action, use sequential `if` blocks, e.g.:

```
if (newState.data == 1) {
  //do something
}
if (anotherCondition) {
  //do something more
}
return false;
```

If multiple conditions need to be true:

```
if (newState.data == 1 && anotherCondition) {
  //do something
  return false;
}
```

Comment: your top answer is essentially what I did and it does not work (even if I move the return false; line to look like yours. Can you do this even inside of a function?

Comment: @Andrew Whatever is after a `return` statement will never be reached. However, you can have multiple points of exit - like in your code in the question body. Any valid piece of JavaScript can go inside a function. I think you need to expand on the `do something here` parts of your example in order for us to get close to a qualified answer.

Comment: I am using the if statement to pause and resume an image rotator (which is where the video will be in). So for the first if statement the code is: $('#slideshow').cycle('pause'); and the second is: $('#slideshow').cycle('resume');. Does that help?

Comment: @Andrew Yes, this means that it is indeed an either-or. What properties does `newState` hold? And what are the possible values of `newState.date`?